# why does this Dart code give "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition"?

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

Why does this Dart code give "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition"?

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static late Database _database;

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;  // HERE: "The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition"
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Database _db = await openDatabase('my_db.db');
    return _db;
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your understanding of the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because checking if `_database` is null is redundant, since you're declaring it as

```
static late Database _database;
```

`Database` here is an non-nullable type, therefore it can't be null.

Just to make it clear, this is a warning rather than an error.

---

To refactor your code, declare the `_database` variable as nullable

```
static Database? _database;
```

and your `database` getter as

```
Future<Database> get database async {
  final Database? instance = _database;
  if (instance != null) return instance;
  instance = await _initDatabase();
  _database = instance;
  return instance;
}
```

Comment: thanks - do you think making it nullable is better than marking it as "late"?  Would seem better/more robust no?

Comment: oh - just noted instance has to be non-final in your example when putting it into vscode fyi

Comment: If you use `late`, you can't check if the field is initialized or not. So in this case, using a nullable type would be the right choice, since you can check if the field is initialized by checking if it's not null.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you define `_database`, you specifically defined it as non-nulable:

```
static late Database _database;
```

If it was a nullable one, you would add the "?"

```
static late Database? _database;
```